# Regular expression, lost result group

Tags: c++, regex

My cpp application is trying to parse a string with pattern:

```
^\/color( set| update)? (#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})|([a-zA-Z]{1,20})$
```

**Test run**

/color set #ffffff -  get 2 groups('set and '#ffffff')
[image]

/color set red - get 1 group with 'red', what happened to the group with 'set'?
[image]

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @NathanOliver "what happened to the group with 'set'? "

Comment: @NathanOliver the operation **set** is not captured in the second example, where color names are used instead of hex values

Comment: Please check out the precedence of the `|` operator in regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is, you have an  incorrect / unnecessary grouping. Use the following :

```
^\/color\s(set|update)?\s?(#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|#[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}|[a-zA-Z]{1,20})$
```

**[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yr3Tkw/2)**

Comment: Thank you. I will accept this as answer, but your pattern fails against /color  red (if just one space between) that is why I put space in a result group

Comment: The problem is with `\s(set|update)?\s`. It must be `(?:\s(set|update))?`

Comment: @danilabagroff need to make the space optional. check edit

Comment: If I guess OP's intent correctly, it should be `…|#[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}|…` not `…|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}|…`.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with this section of the regex.

```
(#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})|([a-zA-Z]{1,20})
```

With the way you have them grouped and the precedence of the OR operator, it is basically being evaluated as capture if either of these two regexes are true:

```
^\/color( set| update)? (#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})
([a-zA-Z]{1,20})$
```

Because of the string "/color set red" not matching the hexadecimal check, it determines the left side is false and only the right is true. Hence, why it is capturing the right.

I suggest rewriting your regex as this. This way it accounts for one or more space and tab characters between each argument in the string.

```
^\/color[ \t]*(set|update)?[ \t]+(\#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}|[a-zA-Z]{1,20})$
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added named groups and fixed an issue with the second whitespaces, which lead to `/color red` not being matched, in the case of the operation being omitted.

`^\/color\s+(?<op>set|update)?\s*(?<color>#[AFaf09]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}|[a-zA-Z]{1,20})\s*$`

[Click here](https://regex101.com/r/H0VsAQ/1) to test the regex. Also, below you'll find a version without named captures, since *SebastianRedl* pointed out, that C++ does not support this feature.

`^\/color\s+(set|update)?\s*(#[AFaf09]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}|[a-zA-Z]{1,20})\s*$`

Comment: C++ regex does not support named captures.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Okay, I'll add another version.